# How to modify element's data during import?

Tags: plugin-feedme

I'm trying to modify the element's data during the import. I'm using EVENT_STEP_BEFORE_ELEMENT_SAVE to modify the $contentData. I added some logging at each step and I can see that the $contentData is being changed to " - blah - " for each element in the feed but the original value for 'productDescription' is still being saved for the element.

```
Event::on(Process::class, Process::EVENT_STEP_BEFORE_ELEMENT_SAVE, function(FeedProcessEvent $event) {
 $event->contentData['productDescription'] = " - blah - ";         
});
```

Here's the logging (irrelevant data omitted):

```
{before modifying ($contentData) ==== "productDescription":"Freestanding Spring Horses"}
{after modifying ($contentData) ::::: "productDescription":" - blah - "}
{Data ready to import ($contentData) -> "productDescription":" - blah - "}
{After saving ($contentData) ---- "productDescription":" - blah - "}
```

When I look at the productDescription field for the element that was just imported I see: "Freestanding Spring Horses"

So how can I modify the data that gets saved for each element?

Answer (score 1):

The `EVENT_STEP_BEFORE_ELEMENT_SAVE` is actually fired after the content has been applied to element attributes and field content.

Instead, you'll want to modify the element's content directly. You can do this via:

```
$event->element->productDescription = " - blah - ";
```

As the plugin author, I may change this so it acts as you've suggested. Currently, modifying `$contentData` essentially does nothing. However, this will require a change to the event where it passes in `attributeData` and `fieldData` separately, as they need to be applied separately back on the element. I'll look at adding this in the next version.

Let me know if that doesn't work!